# Map Reduce Keep input ordering

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I tried to implement an application using hadoop which processes text files.The problem is that I cannot keep the ordering of the input text.Is there any way to choose the hash function?This problem could be easily solved by assigning a partition of the input to each mapper an then send the partition to the reducers.Is this possible with hadoop ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'ordering of the input text'? What kind of a MapReduce job are you running?

Comment: I am writing a program that edit the files.But because I have very very very big files i need to use map reduce.But I cannot understand the correct model.If my mapper send just modified words to the reduces then the output will be just a bag of words....The approach I thought is every mapper to use a part of the files and then use a secondary sort on the reducers

Answer (score 2):

The base idea of MapReduce is that the order in which things are done is irrelevant.
So you cannot (and do not need to) control the order in which:

- the input records go through the mappers.
- the key and related values go through the reducers.

The only thing you can control is the order in which the values are placed in the iterator that is made available in the reducer.
This is done using a construct called "secondary sort".

A simple google action for [this term](http://www.google.nl/search?q=secondary%20sort%20hadoop) resulted in several points where you can continue.
I like this blog post : [link](http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/secondary-sorting-aka-sorting-values-in-hadoops-mapreduce-programming-paradigm/)

Comment: I have a simlar problem. My textinputformat.record.delimiter gives very big values to the map function which results in heap space error. And if I use a smaller chunk, I lose order and hence can't implement the functionality. Anyway to tackle big input chunks?

Comment: @stolen_leaves Create your own inputformat. Add a number indicating the order during reading. Then at a later moment you can order it all again using this sequence number.